# What does this C program terminate as soon as it takes a input?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, logic, execution

This is my first question here, so I apologize in advance.

Whenever it executes it just takes one number as input and then terminates.
Can't, we use this logic to find out the greatest and smallest number among any numbers??

```c
#include<stdio.h>  

void main()
{
    int *p,n,i,max,min;
    printf("How many numbers?= ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nStart entering numbers\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){   
        scanf("%d",(p+i));
    }
    max=*(p+0);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(*(p+i)>max)
        {max=*(p+i);}
    }
    printf("Maximum number = %d\n",max);
    min=*(p+0);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(*(p+i)<min)
            min=*(p+i);
    }
    printf("Minimum number = %d",min);    
}
```

Whenever it executes, it just takes one number as input and then terminates.

Can't,we use this logic to find out the greatest and smallest number among any numbers?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please apply proper indentation to your code. Readability is important. Especially for beginners.

Comment: General notes: You should always check return value of `scanf` and you should enable warnings in your compiler. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It should tell you about using `p` without assigning a value first.

Comment: You could improve readability even more by using array syntax instead of explicit pointer arithmetics: `*(p+i)` is same as `p[i]` and `p+i` is same as `&p[i]`

Comment: @Gerhardh, please send me this complete solution. although I edited the code as mentioned by you the same problem repeats again and again.

Comment: explain what p is pointing to.

Comment: What I pointed out was not solving the issue. That was already identified by xing before my comments. My comments were about better readability and good practice during development.

Comment: Another side note: Return type for `main` should be `int`

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have a pointer to a `int` called `p` that points to nothing, it is empty.

Then you call `scanf()` and read into the empty pointer `p`.

```
scanf("%d",(p+i));
```

This will not work since `p` points to nothing and when `scanf()` tries to store something inside it, it will most likely lead to a segmentation fault or undefined behaviour.

To fix it you could allocate memory for `p` with `malloc()`:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

if (p == NULL)
{
     fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed");
    // error procedure
}
```

This will create an array capable of storing `n` elements of type `int`.

Notes:

- Your code uses a lot of `*(p+i)`s, this could cause confusion and lead to error prone code, it is best that you use `p[i]` instead.
- Your `main` function has return type `void`, instead you should use `int` so you can return a error code of some sort if something fails.
- You should test the return value of `scanf` to see if it failed to read something from the user.

Comment: "`p` that points to nothing, it is empty." is more like `p` is uninitialized - it does certainly point to _nothing_.  `p+i` is then simply _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behaviour here: You're declaring a pointer `p` and start assigning values not only to the memory location of `p` but also of subsequent pointers `p+1`, `p+2` etc. But you've never checked if the system allocated available memory to you. You may be lucky and get a pointer to a memory address that has sufficient contiguous memory available to hold all the values that follow, but you can't rely on that.

A better way would be:

```
int n,i,max,min;
if (!(scanf("%d",&n))) return;
printf("\nStart entering numbers\n");
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
if (p == NULL) return;
```

Essentially, you want to use `malloc()` (for which you will have to `#include <stdlib.h>` to allocate as much memory as you need for the numbers. For good practice, you also want to check whether the `scanf` and the `malloc` worked out right, which is the job of the two `if` statements that terminate the program in case something went wrong. If not, you can be sure to have the memory you need, and the program can go on.

In terms of notation, you can use `*(p+1)` etc if you want to, but it's more common (and more readable) to use `p[1]`, and in fact the C standard requires the two to be equivalent.

Comment: Aside: Consider `p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * n)` instead of `p = malloc(sizeof(int)*n)`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Answer (score -1):

If the number of p members is very small, I (personally) wouldn't do the job with malloc(), and then (one souldn't forget!) free();

I would just do something like
int p[100];
instead of *p, and to refer like p[0] or p[i] to them instead of using pointers.

Comment: While the answer to the question can be found it you really look for it, you should be much more clear in your answer. At first glance, it does not look like you're even attempting the actual problem.